# Owin returning null on API login (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this api controller that I use to authenticate my users

```
public class UsersData : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private readonly LoggingController logger = (LoggingController)LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(typeof(LoggingController));
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;


        public UsersData()
        {
            logger.ConfigureLogger();
            logger.SetApplicationName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"]);
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        public bool AuthenticateUser(LoginDTO Input)
        {
            var user = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == Input.Email);
            var passwordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Input.Password);
            if(passwordHash == user.PasswordHash)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I access it via Postman at http://localhost:9000/api/authentication?username=user@onae.com&password=1, it returns this error `$exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.NullReferenceException`

Am I doing something wrong? It looks like the issue is in the UserManager that is returning null? But I'm not sure how I can fix this.

### Edit

```
return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

This line is the one that returns null. How do I reinitialise the user manager? I thought I did it already.

Comment: If you can, you should debug your code and figure out which object in the code is NULL and make sure that it is initialized properly or handle the exception properly.

Comment: I have debugged and this line is the one that returns null. return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

Comment: Looks like `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` is returning null

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah. How do I authenticate a user via api then?